# Bitnami + Nginx, change IP address to domain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, bitnami

I have simple question - How do I change the Bitnami (lightsail) Nginx - Wordpress IP address to an domain?

I have followed the documentation here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-pro/administration/use-single-domain-nginx/

and when I go to my domain now I have Nginx welcome screen... I have to go to mydomain/wordpress to see 404 page of my website.

Where am I going wrong?

I am guessing there is some 'routing' that tells the server where to take website from. Unfortunately, I am new to Nginx...

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bitnami engineer here. If your WordPress' deployment works properly when using your ip, you will need to configure your DNS provider to point to that IP and configure WordPress to use your domain when building the different links. You will need to edit the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL parameters in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: @JotaMartos I have that... DNS pointing to the server, wp-config.php updated... When I access the domain now I can see Bitnami/Nginx welcome screen - if I go mydomain.com/wordpress I can see the site but its all broken (no styles loaded etc.). This is why I am confused - I went through every tutorial out there and nothing works. I am either getting 403 error or the welcome screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after hours of changing .conf files I got it.

The answer that pointed me in right direction: https://community.bitnami.com/t/point-domain-without-sub-directory-in-nginx-bitnami/70415/6 by davidg

Just to quickly sum up...
I changed this file: `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-prefix.conf`
from:

```
location /wordpress {
   alias "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs";
   include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
```

to:

```
location / {
    root "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs";
    include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
```

The bitnami documentation is a bit misleading (at least for me!) when it comes to changing the IP to domain.